Webpack is not resolving alias properly
I am trying to set up path aliases in my JavaScript project using Webpack, but I'm running into issues with the alias not being recognized, despite it working in my IDE (VSCode).
Here’s the relevant section of my jsconfig.json file where I defined the path alias:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}

Problem:
When I import modules using the alias in my code, such as:
import { myFunction } from '@/utils/myFunction';

Webpack throws an error saying that it cannot find the module. This works fine in my IDE (VSCode), which recognizes the alias, but it fails during the Webpack build process.
What I Have Tried:
Ensured that the path alias in jsconfig.json is correctly set.
Verified that my directory structure matches the aliasing.
Questions:
How can I ensure that Webpack recognizes the path alias defined in tsconfig.json?
Is there a better way to set up path aliases that works seamlessly with Webpack and JavaScript?
Additional Information:
I’m using plain JavaScript (not TypeScript) for this project.
Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
